# mailto link in internet explorer navigates to dead end

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, mailto

I am using an anchor with mailto, and I am finding that the behavior is extremely unrefined.

```
<a id="Help" href="mailto:abc_123@domain.com">Questions</a>
```

when I do this in IE8, I find that in some locations, the windows asks if it can open outlook, you say yes, and it opens a new email message and sets the To: section. It also leaves the browser window in the same site that I came from.

When I do this in my implementation with the above link, I find that the browser navigates to  mailto:abc_123@domain.com, and shows an ugly: Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage error.  What do I need to do to make this work nicely, like the above case?  Finally, it fails to leave the browser in the original location that I came from.

Edit: I just noticed that the badly behaving version is local host and the good behaving version is on a production server.  Could that make a difference?

Comment: Whats make the different between the two cases?

Comment: is that an exact copy paste from your broken anchor?  did you possibly miss the colon (:) or anything like that?

Comment: that's an exact copy and paste, with address changed very slightly.  _ was left in.  The difference between the two cases is one is implemented on a very large webpage, the other is a relatively new webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem appears to be that IE has problems with long mailto links.

[mailto fails in IE where there is a long body text. Is there any way to resolve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241274/mailto-fails-in-ie-with-long-body-any-resolution)

Keep your links less than 512 characters, and you should see fewer problems when using IE.

Answer (score 1):

I notice you've tagged this with jQuery. Is it possible that there is an event handler being added to the link which does something like this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    window.location.href = this.href;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: interesting, I will look for that

Comment: do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: nope, didn't work.  It seems to work intermittently, and perhaps a little more frequently.  Perhaps I should change the question to be: "Why does IE suck?"

Answer (score 0):

This is completely in your browser.

Go into Folder Options (Control Panel), File Types, and see what handler
is associated with the URL:Mailto protocol. You'll have to click on
Advanced and edit the 'open' action to see what is the handler/server
for that filetype association.