# ie9 mailto link character limit bug carried over from ie8?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, mailto

I found this question:

[mailto fails in IE where there is a long body text. Is there any way to resolve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241274/mailto-fails-in-ie-where-there-is-a-long-body-text-is-there-any-way-to-resolve)

and decided to remove the body of my mailto just to test... And it worked.

So it this character limit bug still in place for ie9? Has anybody else had similar problems?

**UPDATE**

My mail-to seems to work on ie8, but not ie9.. Guess I'm getting closer to solving it though.

Comment: I am facing it. Also the solution doesn't work in my case (working in IE8)

Answer (score 0):

This answer by jimwvisi help me: [Mailto: link does not work](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/mailto-link-does-not-work-in-ie8-but-works-in/b23a1005-590f-4dc4-9770-0331d096e48e)

After an upgrade by admin from IE8 to IE9 (and possibly other system changes too), ‘mailto:’ navigation would result in the ‘about:blank’ page being shown, and no activation of the mail client.

Reducing the length of the ‘mailto:’ string to below approx. 500 characters made things look right again, but that is not a very usable solution. The work-around suggested by jimwvis is better: activate IE’s Internet settings->security->local intranet->activate cures/hides the problem (the security level does not seem to be important)