# mailto not opening on IE11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-11, mailto

In my asp.net application there is a **mailto** link to open email in Outlook. It works fine in all IE versions except IE 11. Do I need to change any settings to get it work on IE 11.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a pretty old problem with the way IE handles the mailto links.

Hopefully this older post can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3283746/1504316