# Increase limit of IE URL length for mailto:

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Is there a way to send a long email (as logn as Chrome allows) using

```
href = "mailto:..."
```

in IE?

It silently fails when the url is too long. It seems to be due to IE's URL length limit. It also won't work if I copy-paste the  long mailto URL into the browser's address bar.

I've tried the solutions here

[mailto fails in IE where there is a long body text. Is there any way to resolve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241274/mailto-fails-in-ie-where-there-is-a-long-body-text-is-there-any-way-to-resolve)

Neither the accepted answer, nor the one with most upvotes, work with long emails, which work fine with Chrome.

Or, is there a way for my users to increase the accepted URL length of their browser? Chrome's length is fine.

My users type text into an editor and then they need to be able to email this text using their own email program.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was on the URL format. It contained a '#' so I replaced hash char with the corresponding [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) string '%23'. Have you got breaking chars?