# Using a mailto link that doesn't redirect

Tags: html, browser, mailto

I have a situation where I want a mailto: link with a populated subject and body. The link appears in the middle of a wizard flow where we let the users send an email to someone (or themselves) with a copy of what's on the screen.

For users with Gmail set up to handle mailto links, this is a problem. When they click the link they are redirected to Gmail in the tab - but they aren't finished with the wizard and their state is not stored.

We tried adding a target="_blank", to force a new tab, but it turns out that doesn't work in IE. The tab opens but the mailto does not take effect.

Has anyone tried this before? Any ideas on how to fix it for both scenarios?

Comment: Can you show us your html?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mailto fails in IE where there is a long body text. Is there any way to resolve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241274/mailto-fails-in-ie-where-there-is-a-long-body-text-is-there-any-way-to-resolve)

Comment: Yeah, it turns out our e-mail is too long. And well, we just decided to go in another direction entirely... Sorry for taking up your time.